# open k files in paraview

Tags: file, types, paraview, reader

Can I open k files in paraview？

I tried to open a file using the vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader class, but it didn't work. I expected it to read the file and create a mesh object for me, but instead it gave an error message. The actual result was that the file couldn't be read and nothing was created.

Comment: > Can I open k files in paraview？

Yes